# Dummy table for HSQLDB, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS is giving blank

Tags: hsqldb

```
Select 'S' Size from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS;
```

or

```
Select 'S' Size from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS WHERE 1 = 0;
```

BOTH query, resulted in only Size label is printed:

```
SIZE
====
```

My desired result for dummy table:

```
SIZE
====
S
```

Could anyone advice on this?

**p.s I'm running on old version HSQLDB (can't upgrade, office environment)**

Answer (score 0):

With any database, including HSQLDB, your query will return an empty result. The condition `WHERE 1 = 0` is always false, so any row that exists will fail the test.

Try without the condition, and add a LIMIT to guarantee no more than one row is returned.

```
Select 'S' Size from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS LIMIT 1;
```

If you cannot get the right result from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS, then create a table and insert only one row in that table. You can then select from the new table.

```
create table myTable (id int)
insert into myTable values 1
select 'S' Size from MYTABLE
```

Comment: i see, However, provided query still give me blank

Comment: Which version of HSQLDB are you using? Use `call database_version()` if you don't know.

Comment: unfortunately, my version doesn't support database_version() too, but it does support database()

Comment: Updated the answer with alternative